# ServiceUnavailable in Neo4j while creating a relationship between nodes

Tags: sql, ubuntu, neo4j, graph-databases

I have newly started with Neo4j and trying to create relationships for huge data.

I have already added few relationships and now while trying to create a relationship the following error is seen.

> ServiceUnavailable WebSocket connection failure. Due to security
>   constraints in your web browser, the reason for the failure is not
>   available to this Neo4j Driver. Please use your browsers development
>   console to determine the root cause of the failure. Common reasons
>   include the database being unavailable, using the wrong connection URL
>   or temporary network problems. If you have enabled encryption, ensure
>   your browser is configured to trust the certificate Neo4j is
>   configured to use. WebSocket `readyState` is: 3

This is the query I am trying to run

```
MATCH (p:students),(c:results)
WHERE p.id = c.student_id
create (c)-[:scored]->(p)
```

students and exams have around 300000 nodes each.

This is happening only while creating a relationship. 
But it didn't happen when I ran a return query for the same match

```
MATCH (p:students),(c:results)
WHERE p.id = c.student_id
return c.student_id
```

I tried checking logs but couldn't find any solution. Can someone help me understand what the error indicates and how to resolve if anyone encountered a similar issue.

Note: I am running this on Ubuntu machine with remote host.

Answer (score 1):

A creation of 300000 relationships at a time can be a costly operation, mostly in terms of heap usage, as you're performing this in a single transaction.

A better approach would be to batch this insertion (usually 10k per transaction is a sweet spot). [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/index32.html#_apoc_periodic_iterate) is the go-to solution for this, in particular `apoc.periodic.iterate()`.

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
 'MATCH (p:students),(c:results)
  WHERE p.id = c.student_id
  RETURN p, c',
 'CREATE (c)-[:scored]->(p)',
 {iterateList:true, parallel:false}) YIELD batches, total, errorMessages
RETURN batches, total, errorMessages
```

The other big thing to check is that you have indexes (or unique constraints) on both :students(id) and :results(student_id) so your lookups are fast, otherwise periodic iterate will hang, as this would become a high cost operation.

Run an EXPLAIN on your original query and make sure it's first using a NodeByLabelScan for one of those nodes, and then a NodeByIndexSeek to find other.